# Vertical DIV alignment within Bootstrap 3 Grid with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3, and I have problems when I want to align vertically two div, for example ( http://jsfiddle.net/Xelnag/335nhneq/ )

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 vbox">
        <img src="img/1.png" class="icon-16"/> 
        <img src="img/2.png" class="icon-16"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="img/3.png" class="icon-32"/> 
        <img src="img/4.png" class="icon-32"/> 
        <img src="img/5.png" class="icon-32"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for "vbox" is just a vertical align:

```
.vbox { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

What i would like to see is left div aligned to bottom to match the right side.

I have seen answers in stackoverflow with the use of javascript but so far i have found none that works with just CSS with the bootstrap 3 responsive design.

Comment: <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top:12px;"> ?

Comment: yes, that would work, but i was thinking if there was a more dynamic approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way. You need to follow below code.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harnishdesign/335nhneq/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="table-container">
        <div class="col-xs-6 vbox" style="border:1px solid #000">
            <img src="img/1.png" class="icon-16"/> 
            <img src="img/2.png" class="icon-16"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 vbox" style="border:1px solid #F00">
            <img src="img/3.png" class="icon-32"/> 
            <img src="img/4.png" class="icon-32"/> 
            <img src="img/5.png" class="icon-32"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-container .vbox {display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.table-container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.icon-16
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.icon-32
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```